# sbt-release not able to git push

Tags: git, jenkins, sbt-release

I'm trying to build a sbt project with jenkins. I'm getting the following error when doing a sbt clean "release with-defaults" :

```
[info] Starting release process off commit: ce6dcb5a1fdbf5330766e47f3adb26ebc5082c8d
java.lang.RuntimeException: No tracking branch is set up. Either configure a remote tracking branch, or remove the pushChanges release part.
```

The remote branches seem to be set fine. Following is the output of some of the git commands:

```
git --version
git version 1.8.3.1

git branch -r
* master ce6dcb5 debug jenkins
  origin/master

git branch -av
* master                ce6dcb5 debug jenkins
  remotes/origin/master ce6dcb5 debug jenkins

git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://git@stash:7999/~analya/docker-test.git
  Push  URL: ssh://git@stash:7999/~analya/docker-test.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `git branch -u origin/master` works for me

Answer (score 8):

I had this same error but I was working on a branch `dev`.

When I entered `git push origin` it whined a bit and suggested `git push --set-upstream origin dev`, which did the trick.

Comment: You can also use the shorthand -u flag: git push -u origin <branch>

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [GitHub issue 100](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/issues/100):

You can run the following commands in Jenkins before the sbt release command:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

to track the remote master branch so that sbt can push correctly.